# If/else suggests package description

Tags: r, package

Is there a way to do an ifelse statement in the suggests field of a package dependent upon OS type.  For instance the `installr` package would be nice for a windows user and heavily related to a package but it's only available for Windows users.  This means that a note will be raised in the CRAN check for a Mac or Linux user.

Currently I have a package that looks something like this:

```
Package: awesomeR
Type: Package
Title: A collection of awesomeness
Version: 0.1.2
Date: 2013-02-18
Author: Guy Smiley
Maintainer: Guy <guy@gmail.com>
Description: it's pretty nifty
License: GPL-2
URL: http://crazyville
LazyData: TRUE
Depends:
    R (>= 2.15)
Suggests:
    pander,
    installr,
```

Maybe the answer is either suggest it (and accept the notes) or don't.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need special switch for Suggests according to OS for the cran check.

If it does not exist on/for a particular platform it will not get installed. I think such a package will not even be in the CRAN dependancies.

As far as I am concerned - Suggested packages hint to additional options and extend examples and functionality, but are not crucial for your package and a lot of users will not miss them ... but even if one is a Linux or MAc user, I think it is good to know that there is that suggested packages available ... and if they want they can use it on a different platform.

So my answer is - suggest it.

Also I think we should anyway strive towards cross-platform packages =)

Comment: This was question was about package development.  I don't like to get notes on the CRAN check.